# infinite enumerator rewind

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have a function that generates an enumerator in the following manner:

```
def create_example_enumerator(starting_value)
  current = starting_value
  e = Enumerator.new do |y|
    loop do
      current += 1
      y << current
    end
  end
end
```

The current behavior is pretty straightforward.

```
> e = create_example_enumerator(0)
#<Enumerator: details>
> e.next
1
> e.next
2
> e.rewind
#<Enumerator: details>
> e.next
3
```

I would like `e.rewind` to reset the enumerator back to it's starting value.
Is there a nice way to do that while still using an infinite enumerator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
n = Enumerator.new do |y|
  number = 1
  loop do
    y.yield number
    number += 1
  end
end

n.next #=> 1
n.next #=> 2
n.next #=> 3
n.rewind
n.next #=> 1
```

Comment: You may want to put in words the solution: "the variable must be defined inside the enumerator block", since you also change `<<` for `yield` it seems that's the problem. Any idea why is that necessary?

Comment: I think it makes sense -- Rewind should just start over from the start of the block.  If you don't define the initial number inside the block, then your number won't change when you start back over from the start of the block.